# css flexbox Позиционирование

Tags: css, flexbox

Есть 7 блоков внутри родительского, надо сделать через flexbox, что бы эти блоки шли друг под другом в 2 колонки.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Друг за другом - это в столбик или в строку? Пронумеровал бы. И они специально разного размера, или ты их криво нарисовал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить перенос элементов на новую строку, для контейнера в котором будут ваши дивы, это делается css свойством `flex-wrap: wrap;` конечно же для начала добавив свойство `display: flex;` =). Для самих дивов нужно дать ширину и отступы по бокам, чтобы дивы не слипались

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}
.left-bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.main-content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main-content .item {
  width: 45%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.right-bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<main>
<section class="left-bar">
</section>
<section class="main-content">
  <div class="item">
  1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  5
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  6
  </div>
</section>
<section class="right-bar">
</section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

для родителя:

```
parentBlock {
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: flex-start; // либо space-between;
   padding: количество_px;
}
```

для дочерних:

```
children {
    width: 45%; // или какая Вам ширина нужна
    margin: px px;
}
```